# Sharing a nested object between Python processes with write access for tasklets(coroutines)?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, coroutine, greenlets, object-sharing

How can I share a nested object between Python processes with write access for tasklets(coroutines)?

Here is a simplified example with an analogy just I wrote for asking this question properly;

First of all please install `greenlet` package with: `sudo pip install greenlet`

In the example below:

- An instance of `Nature` class referenced by `habitat` variable
- This instance of `Nature` class has an instance variable called `animals`
- While the initiation of this instance of `Nature` class, 8 different instances of `Animal` class created and appended to `animals` instance variable. Now if I'm correct this instance of `Nature` is a nested object.
- As the last step `live` instance functions of `Animal` instances randomly switching using `greenlet` package's `switch()` function until `global_counter` reaches to 1000. This `live` function randomly changing the value of `limbs` instance variable of `Animal` instances.

**greentest.py**:

```
import random
from greenlet import greenlet

global_counter = 0

class Animal():

    def __init__(self,nature):
        self.limbs = 0
        nature.animals.append(self)
        self.tasklet = greenlet(self.live)

    def live(self,nature):
        global global_counter
        while True:
            self.limbs = random.randint(1, 10)
            global_counter += 1
            if global_counter > 1000:
                break
            random.sample(nature.animals,1)[0].tasklet.switch(nature)

class Nature():

    def __init__(self,how_many):
        self.animals = []
        for i in range(how_many):
            Animal(self)
        print str(how_many) + " animals created."
        self.animals[0].live(self)
```

The result is:

```
>>> import greentest
>>> habitat = greentest.Nature(8)
8 animals created.
>>> habitat.animals[0].limbs
3
>>> greentest.global_counter
1002
```

Working as expected. Changing the value of `limbs` and `global_counter` (non-zero)

But when I add `multiprocessing` to the equation;

**greentest2.py**:

```
import random
import multiprocessing
from greenlet import greenlet

global_counter = 0

class Animal():

    def __init__(self,nature):
        self.limbs = 0
        nature.animals.append(self)
        self.tasklet = greenlet(self.live)

    def live(self,nature):
        global global_counter
        while True:
            self.limbs = random.randint(1, 10)
            global_counter += 1
            if global_counter > 1000:
                break
            random.sample(nature.animals,1)[0].tasklet.switch(nature)

class Nature():

    def __init__(self,how_many):
        self.animals = []
        for i in range(how_many):
            Animal(self)
        print str(how_many) + " animals created."
        #self.animals[0].live(self)
        jobs = []
        for i in range(2):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.animals[0].live, args=(self,))
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()
```

The result is not as expected:

```
>>> import greentest2
>>> habitat = greentest2.Nature(8)
8 animals created.
>>> habitat.animals[0].limbs
0
>>> greentest2.global_counter
0
```

Both the values of `limbs` and `global_counter` is unchanged (zero). I think this is because instances of `Animal` class and `global_counter`is not shared between processes. So how can I share this instance of `Nature` class or these instances of `Animal` class between processes?

**ADDITION** according to @noxdafox 's answer;

**greentest3.py**:

```
import random
import multiprocessing
from greenlet import greenlet

global_counter = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)

class Animal():

    def __init__(self,nature):
        self.limbs = 0
        nature.animals.append(self)
        self.tasklet = greenlet(self.live)

    def live(self,nature):
        global global_counter
        while True:
            self.limbs = random.randint(1, 10)
            global_counter.value += 1
            if global_counter.value > 1000:
                break
            random.sample(nature.animals,1)[0].tasklet.switch(nature)

class Nature():

    def __init__(self,how_many):
        self.animals = []
        for i in range(how_many):
            Animal(self)
        print str(how_many) + " animals created."
        #self.animals[0].live(self)
        jobs = []
        for i in range(2):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.animals[0].live, args=(self,))
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()
```

and then result is:

```
>>> import greentest3
>>> habitat = greentest3.Nature(8)
8 animals created.
>>> habitat.animals[0].limbs
0
>>> greentest3.global_counter.value
1004
```

I was perfectly aware that `global_counter` can be shared with this method since it's an *integer* but I'm actually asking how to share the instances of `Nature` and `Animal` classes between processes.

Comment: You understood the problem correctly.  A typical solution is to use queue or pipe.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi Could you explain more or could you answer with a little improved version of my code, please.

Comment: I believe the correct term is [_circular references_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference). and you have a list of jobs but don't you need to check if they have finished before assuming they have done their work?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Processes' job is symbolic on my code example. But they will sure write to instances of `Animal` class. Could you explain how can I use *circular references* on my case?

Comment: "Now if I'm correct this instance of `Nature` is a nested object." I think _nested_ is the wrong term, `Nature` has reference to several `Animal` instances and they all have references to `Nature` object, so their references to each other are "circular".  Sorry for not clarifying that in my original comment.

Comment: Why do you need to share the instances of Nature and Animal classes between processes?  That's a huge leap from the original question.    A general purpose distributed computation system such as MapReduce has a master (driver) and multiple worker processes.  The master maps computation tasks to workers, each worker calculates small part of the problem, then finally the master collects the results back from workers.  Unless the worker is stateless (no inter dependency between workers) the computation would be complicated (race conditions, mutex, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different processes do not share their memory.

If what you need to share is a single variable, you probably can use [multiprocessing.Value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value)

```
import multiprocessing

def function(counter):
    counter.value += 1

counter = multiprocessing.Value('i')
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(counter))
p.start()
p.join()
```

EDIT: answering according to updates.

There is no abstraction mechanism allowing to share entire objects in memory. Shared memory is usually implemented as a simple array where processes can read/write once acquired the resource.

Moreover, OOP and threading/multiprocessing don't mix well together. IMHO should be considered an anti-pattern. On top of complex objects, you add the concurrent access and modification of their properties. This is a one way ticket for long and tedious debugging sessions.

The recommended pattern is the use of message queues. Imagining Threads and Processes as isolated entities which communicates via specific channels significantly simplifies the problem.

Comment: I know but how can I share the object. Sharing an integer is easy but I don't know how to share the instances of `Nature` and  `Animal` classes.